# Are there cheaper alternatives to standard UV photography equipment?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, uv

I am familiar with the standard lens/filter system often used - [the UV-Nikkor 105mm f/4.5s lens](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/special/105UVmm.htm), what I am wondering is if there are cheaper alternatives to this standard (which I believe is also discontinued?).  Is it possible to be able to obtain such equipment for less than say US $500?

Comment: Those photos look like someone vomited rainbows! Bizarre effect!

Comment: +1 for the vomiting rainbows comment!  It is very bizarre to think that this is how some species see the world.

Comment: Reflected UV in which spectral band?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with UV photography is that standard optical glass filters out UV light, so lens designers have to turn to more exotic formulations such as phosphate glass, or other materials such as quartz. This fact combined with the very low production volumes are not a good recipe for cheap lenses.

I can't answer with a hundred percent certainty, but the only UV lens I know of in production is the [Coastal Optics UV/vis/IR 60mm macro](http://www.jenoptik-inc.com/coastalopt-standard-lenses/uv-vis-nir-60mm-slr-lens-mainmenu-155.html) lens which sells new for $4500, and the only other lenses I know of in the used market were by Zeiss and Rodenstock. And I'm afraid you don't often hear the phrase "rare Zeiss lens" or "rare Rodenstock lens" in the same sentance as "under $500"...

**update**

You can rent the Coastal Optics UV-vis-IR lens from **[lensrentals.com](https://www.lensrentals.com/rent/nikon/lenses/specialty/coastal-optics-uv-vis-ir-60mm-macro-for-nikon)** for three weeks for $531

Comment: Thank you for this, I had a feeling that this would be the case. It is understandable though, quartz and fluorite lenses would be more expensive. I have had published research that indeed shows the usual glass attenuates UV severely, particularly below about 360nm.

Answer (score 4):

You can use EL-Nikkor lenses (can be had quite cheaply on eBay) for UV photography.

Hope it is okay if I plug my own site here, as I recently wrote a guide about the equipment and technique I use for UV / multispectral photography: [Vis UV IR flower photography guide](http://vis-uv-ir-flower-photos.blogspot.co.uk/p/vis-uv-ir-flower-photography-guide.html).

Also check out [Dr. Klaus Schmitt's Photography of the invisible world](http://photographyoftheinvisibleworld.blogspot.co.uk/) website for more info on UV photography (including using cheaper non-quartz lenses).

Comment: Thank you for the sites, they are both very relevant - your site is nice and detailed.

Comment: The image in my avatar is a UV image of the sun (more likely the noise surrounding the central image).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly there are quite a few capable lenses for UV work without having to spend $$$$. I have done research on that for years, which may be found on my BLOG uvir.eu and there is a thread summarizing it here: http://photographyoftheinvisibleworld.blogspot.com/2011/01/uv-lenses-tested-good-for-uv.html some of them reaching down to 320nm, more than sufficient for UV flower work as UV nectar patterns usually get visible between 350-380nm.

[image: Bidens VIS-UV]

Comment: Can you summarize, briefly, some inexpensive UV lens options from your blog article? That would make this answer much better for people seeking UV lenses.